# Automatic updates for a VB.NET application

Tags: vb.net, deployment, updates, automatic-updates

In the publish menu of a VB.NET application, I have mentioned "Check for updates" and mentioned the server address.

Both Product Version & File Version is 14_0_0_0 as of now. Now I have made some changes to the application and I want all my users to run the latest update (14_0_0_1).

What are the files I should upload now to the server? And if all the files, then how? Should they be compressed into batch files or setup files?

Answer (score 2):

On the Publish page in the Project Properties window, there is a path that specifies where to publish to. You need to make the contents of that folder available at the location that you specified that your application should look for updates.

Comment: So the new version should be published to the server location. The application will automatically check for updates. Am I right?